# health check of custom repositories in Nexus?

Tags: maven, maven-3, nexus

I have created a repository in Nexus. As I am the owner of this repository, it is of type : Hosted.
I was going through the book of Mastering Apache Maven 3.0 and it says that, it is not possible to perform a health check on the repositories which are

1.The Repository Type is Proxy.
2.The Repository Policy is not Snapshot.
3.The Repository is In Service.

I have the last 2 conditions satisfied in my repository. But, the type of my repository is Hosted as I have the repository in my local machine.

Is there anything which I can do for a health check of custom repositories in Nexus?

I have one more question. If I want to mark an artifact in my hosted repository, how should I do that? Or should I just delete the vulnerable artifact from the repository?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How could nexus perform a health check on your custom libs?

From the [nexus docs](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/rhc.html)

> HDS exposes data about the components in the Central Repository and
>   other public repositories, including license information, security
>   vulnerability data, and other statistics like relative usage
>   popularity and age

HDS is

> Hosted Data Services (HDS) run by Sonatype

None of that is available for your hosted custom libraries. You can't really expect sonatype to maintain a database about them, because it doesn't know about them. If you want this, move your libs to an open-source model with an appropriate licence and upload them to maven central.